# List return method returning an empty list (although list gets filled)

Tags: java, android, list, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm working on an Android app that uses an SQLite database to load data into a list and display it. I have a DatabaseHelper class that deals with CRUD methods for the database. I'm trying to find specific results from a given date, however, although my query returns expected results and fills up a list to return, I can't get this list returned in my Main activity.

My query method:

```
public List<Earthquake>getListByDate(LocalDate dateInput){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + PUB_DATE + " = " + "'"+dateInput+"'", null);

        Log.e("Cursor", ""+data.getColumnCount());
        Log.e("QueryReturnList", ""+QueryReturnList(data));

        return QueryReturnList(data);
    }
```

> **Log:**
>
> E/Cursor: 12
>
> E/returnList: [object, object, object...]
>
> E/QueryReturnList: [object, object, object...]

QueryReturnList: (This method builds a list of objects from the input cursor)

```
    private List<Earthquake>QueryReturnList(Cursor data){

            List<Earthquake>returnList = new ArrayList<>();

            int titleIndex = data.getColumnIndex(TITLE_COL),
                    descIndex = data.getColumnIndex(DESC_COL),
                    //... ;

            while(data.moveToNext()){
                Earthquake e = new Earthquake(
                        data.getString(titleIndex),
                        data.getString(descIndex),
                        //... ;
                );
                returnList.add(e);
            }
            Log.e("returnList",""+returnList);
            return returnList;
        }
```

> **Log:**
>
> E/returnList: [object, object, object...]

As I log these results, they work as expected in the DatabaseHelper. The correct results are found, and QueryReturnList returns the expected list object.

---

However, when I call this list from my main activity and set it to a new list, it appears to be empty when I log it (or debug).

```
List<Earthquake>earthquakes = mDatabaseHelper.getListByDate(currentDateSelection);
Log.e("earthquakesByDate", ""+earthquakes);
```

> **Log:**
>
> E/returnList: []
>
> E/earthquakesByDate: []

---

Why am I getting an empty list returned when it does return and log a filled list initially (in my DatabaseHelper)?

**Note:** It seems to log "returnList" and "QueryReturnList" multiple times while running in an unexpected order. Are the methods not having time to get all the data and return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
Log.e("QueryReturnList", ""+QueryReturnList(data));
```

calls `QueryReturnList(data)`, so after this has finished, the cursor is iterated and because of:

```
while(data.moveToNext())
```

the cursor's pointer is after the last row. 
Then this:

```
return QueryReturnList(data);
```

calls again `QueryReturnList(data)` and when it reaches this:

```
while(data.moveToNext())
```

it skips the loop because `moveToNext()` returns `false`. 
So better drop this line:

```
Log.e("QueryReturnList", ""+QueryReturnList(data));
```

or rewrite `getListByDate()` like this:

```
public List<Earthquake>getListByDate(LocalDate dateInput){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + PUB_DATE + " = " + "'"+dateInput+"'", null);
    Log.e("Cursor", ""+data.getColumnCount());
    List<Earthquake> list = QueryReturnList(data);
    Log.e("QueryReturnList", ""+list);
    return list;
}
```

Comment: This was my issue. I didn't really realise what the Cursor was doing I suppose. Thanks a lot, silly mistake.